# Committee Confusion

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Among the 300 employees of a company, 240 are union members. If sixof the employees are chosen to serve on a committee, what is the probability that four of the six will be union members.

$\binom{300}{6}$ would be a committee of six people who may or may not be union members. We are looking for the probability that *exactly* four members of this committee are union members. But i'm not quite sure how to do this. Can someone explain?

Comment: You need to compare the number of ways of choosing $4$ union members and $2$ non-union members with the number of ways of choosing $6$ employees, as you say ${300 \choose 6}$.

Comment: I was thinking of subtracting out committees with non-union members greater than 2. 300-240 = 60 employees are non union members. So there are $\binom{60}{3}$ possible committees of size 4 of all non-unions. $\binom{60}{4}$, $\binom{60}{5}$, and $\binom{60}{6}$ the same. So, I think the answer should be $\binom{300}{6} - \binom{60}{6} - \binom{60}{5} - \binom{60}{4} - \binom{60}{3}$. Agree?

Comment: A probability is usually between $0$ and $1$.  But in any case, that is not the desired approach.   What is the number of ways of choosing $4$ union members out of $240$?  What is the number of ways of choosing $2$ non-union members out of $300-240$?

Comment: ah, $\frac{\binom{240}{4} \binom{60}{2}}{\binom{300}{6}}$. Can you explain why my initial answer was wrong? What was wrong with the thought process?

Comment: You would have to subtract the number of committees in which the number of union members is not $4$.  $$\frac{\binom{300}{6} - \binom{60}{6} - \binom{60}{5}\binom{240}{1} - \binom{60}{4}\binom{240}{2} - \binom{60}{3}\binom{240}{3} - \binom{60}{1}\binom{240}{5} - \binom{240}{6}}{\binom{300}{6}}$$